# NoSuchFileException while running jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

When we convert code to jar file we get this error.
the code works with IDE

```
public String getwordleString() {

        Path path = Paths.get("..\\termproject\\word_database.txt");
        List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            wordList = Files.readAllLines(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Random random = new Random();
        int position = random.nextInt(wordList.size());
        return wordList.get(position).trim().toUpperCase();
    }
```

Error part is : https://ibb.co/z6vZLW5

Comment: no screenshots of plain text, please!

Comment: Is that file part of the jar? You can't access objects in a jar like that.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Paths.get("..\\termproject\\word_database.txt")` assumes that there is a directory "..\termproject\word_database.txt" starting at the current working directory. If the file does not exist, you will get an error.
If you want to wrap the directory with the JAR, you can set you "termproject" file as a src or class file. Then this will be accessible via `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/word_database.txt")`. Now you can read the text from the file with a BufferedReader like so:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/word_database.txt")));
String data = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

Comment: "starting at the JARs location" -> "starting at the current working directory"

Comment: That is a much clearer way to phrase it. I have updated my answer, Thank You!